# Benchmark JNDI lookup: Spring vs classic

Tags: spring, ejb, benchmarking, jndi, performance

Hi (excuse me for my English)

I'm migrating my app to Spring. I have a question about it.

To lookup EJBs with Spring, I use  and this works perfect for me.

Now I want to benchmark *old invocation* (initial context and then *lookup* method) vs *new* one (*remoteObj* bean instantiation). I'm wrapping the code with *System.currentTimeInMillis()* , but the measures are almost the same.

So, is there any reliable software/Java class... to take reliable measures about this? Then, I could say *Spring JNDI lookup improves in my app* or not.

Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't surprise me the times are almost the same. The differences between the two approaches are not sufficient to warrant there being a measurable difference in performance.

Comment: Ok, Michael. So, the difference is the approach, isn't it? Thank you